# Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'F:\login\uploads\2019-05-12T18:23:38.048Z20190319_214122.jpg'

Tags: node.js

```
Error in path in uploading image by multer.

I tried to give path dependency but that also problem didn't solved. 

const express = require('express');
const mysql = require('promise-mysql');
const path = require('path')
const multer = require('multer')
const storage = multer.diskStorage({
  destination: function(req, file, cb){
    cb(null, '/uploads/')
  },
  filename: function(req, file, cb){
    cb(null, new Date().toISOString() + file.originalname)
  }
});
```

this giving error-Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'F:\login\uploads\2019-05-12T18:23:38.048Z20190319_214122.jpg'

Comment: ':' invalid character for file name

Comment: In which line line can you mention

Comment: Please tell me where to change.

Comment: Where you name the file.

Comment: What about the addressing?  `F:\login\uploads\... `  does that sound correct?

Answer (score 5):

```
cb(null, new Date().toISOString() + file.originalname)
```

change to:

```
cb(null, new Date().toISOString().replace(/[\/\\:]/g, "_") + file.originalname)
```

Date.toISOString() returns the current date and time and contains the character ':', which is prohibited in the Windows file system. It is also possible that the file name contains path delimiters that may not be properly processed. I added a regular expression that replaces the characters ':', '\' and '/' with the character '_'. Now the file name becomes valid.

Comment: Can you explain what this done exactly? Information for further readers